# Getting value from dataframe, processing, and reinserting new value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe called 'data', called as so:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

In this dataframe, there is a column called `feature1`. How can I loop through every row for `feature1`, get its value, do some process to get a new value, and then insert that new value back into the dataframe in its correct position? Thanks very much! :)

Comment: use `df['feature1'] = df['feature1'].apply(func_for_preprocessing)`

Comment: @Dark Thanks very much Dark! By the way, what if it's conditional, like I only want to apply the function for a particular value

Comment: How was your username not taken? I came just for that...

Comment: @pstatix haha! No idea lol..well actually it is taken. By me, haha!

Comment: @Programmer define the conditions inside your function. Use an if else statement. Apply is much like a for loop. If you show us what your actual task is we can help.